# template style in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to WPF and learning WPF, I'm trying to create a  template with following attributes

[image]

TEXT 1 to 6 contains border which is thickness=1

so I developed this task using a Grid

**XML**

```
  <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
        <Grid>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="80" Margin="55,107,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="183">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="54*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="68*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="61*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="22*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="31*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="27*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                </Border>

            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
```

is there any other optimum way to achieve this purpose

*which is place TEXT 1-6 in with border thickness 1 with separate blocks like above picture*

Comment: You could use `Label` instead of `TextBlock` and write a local implicit template for `Label`. That's what I'd do.

Comment: @EdPlunkett okay thanks :) can you give good reference for "write a local implicit template for Label"

Comment: I can give you an unimpeachable one. Just a sec while I paste it into the answer box.

Comment: Fantastic job nailing that other question, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do this with Labels instead of TextBoxes. Labels can have borders.

The trouble here, as you can see, is that some borders double up. But you already had that problem.

Note that with Label, you're putting the content in the `Content` property rather than `Text` as in the TextBlocks.

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
    <Grid>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="80" Margin="55,107,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="183">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="54*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="68*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="61*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="22*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="31*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="27*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.Resources>

                <!-- 
                Here's the 'local implicit style'. 
                "Implicit" means it has no x:Key property, so it will apply to 
                all Labels contained in the Grid here. 
                -->

                <Style TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Label}}">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                    <!-- 
                    Label has a nonzero default margin, we don't want that here. 
                    -->
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
                </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>

            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>
            <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Comment: thnks lot I'll apply this and let u know